# How to centralise swagger-ui docs into a resource accessible via single endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have set up a spring-boot application and I would like the Swagger UI to display all my docs aggregated on a single page.

For background, the app is containerised and running in a cluster with multiple deployments orchestrated by k8s. There is an ingress service that routes to correct deployment depending on structure of the incoming HTTP request.

There are multiple controllers in each module, which is configured with Springfox.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class Swagger
{
    @Bean
    public Docket api()
    {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Above just gives me a default swagger UI page with a document for each endpoint. How to provide a centralised swagger-ui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I have used kubernetes service discovery to register my clients, more info on k8s client discovery: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-kubernetes/2.1.0.RC1/multi/multi__discoveryclient_for_kubernetes.html

I have also created a gateway service API with a zuul proxy, to query the swagger specs, more info on zuul in spring boot:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html

Lastly I've configured my ingress service to redirect all swagger requests to the gateway API, which uses zuul to obtain swagger specs.